# YouTube API v3 embeddable flag

Tags: youtube-data-api

Within the past few weeks, API calls that change the privacy status of a video have been switching the embeddable flag off. The solution is to pass  "embeddable":true with the privacy status. I'm wondering if anyone else has experienced this or is aware of any changes to the Youtube api? I didn't see anything in the changelog. thanks